# Sharepoint - Custom Integer Column - Remove thousand separator in EditForm

Tags: sharepoint-2010, integer

I created a new column definition in Sharepoint 2010 of type integer and with Commas set to false.
A content type uses this column.
When I create a list based on the content type, the "View Item" form will display the field correctly: 2010.
The EditForm however will display it as 2,010: with a comma although commas is set to false.

This is a new integer field (not a number field converted to integer)

Any ideas how to display 2,010 as 2010 in the EditForm?

```
 <Field
  ID="{FF3B3FA8-AF33-4691-AD7E-1463DC024B99}"
  Name="studyYear"
  StaticName="studyYear"
  DisplayName="Study year"
  Title="Year"
  Description="Study year"
  Required="FALSE"
  Group="Custom Columns"
  Type="Integer"
  Commas="FALSE"
  Min="1900"
  Max="2300"
  MaxLength="4">
 </Field>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to group list items by Year based the Created field, but needed to covert number to text to avoid 1000 separator (,)

So I created a calculated field with formula of =LEFT(YEAR(Created),1)&RIGHT(YEAR(Created),3)

Comment: Thanks Archie.  The problem is that the issue occurrs in the edit form, so I cannot use a calculated field.

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom field definition that I created in SharePoint 2010.

I basically followed the pattern set forth [in this MS walkthrough.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861799.aspx) - then I changed their custom 'Field' example which inherits from 'SPFieldText' to instead inherit from SPFieldNumber, and my FieldControl inherits from NumberField.

Also, here's my field definition XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FieldTypes>
  <FieldType>
    <Field Name="TypeName">Wps</Field>
    <Field Name="SQLType">int</Field>
    <Field Name="InternalType">Integer</Field>
    <Field Name="ParentType">Number</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeDisplayName">Client WPS integer</Field>
    <Field Name="TypeShortDescription">Client WPS number</Field>
    <Field Name="UserCreatable">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="ShowOnListCreate">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="ShowOnSurveyCreate">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="ShowOnDocumentLibraryCreate">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="ShowOnColumnTemplateCreate">TRUE</Field>
    <Field Name="FieldTypeClass">MyCompany.SharePoint.WpsField, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Field>
  </FieldType>
</FieldTypes>
```

Like Karel, I had defined everything well enough that all commas were squashed.. except in the edit form.

I ended up adding some javascript to the custom .ascx that is part of my custom field definition.

```
 <%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
    <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
    <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
    <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
    <%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
    <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
    <%@ Control Language="VB" %>
    <SharePoint:RenderingTemplate ID="WpsFieldControl" runat="server">
      <Template>
        <span id="commaField">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextField" runat="server"  Width="120px" />
        </span>
        <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
            var numFld = document.getElementById("commaField").childNodes[0];
            numFld.value = numFld.value.replace(",", "");
          // ]]>
        </script>
      </Template>
    </SharePoint:RenderingTemplate>
```

Note that I wrapped my ASP.NET TextBox in a simple SPAN with an ID that I could easily locate the field using getElementById in my JS. This was acceptable in my scenario, because the nature of our business would only ever require a single instance of my field type on a given SharePoint list record.

This seemed to solve everything for me! Maybe not the prettiest, but, I like that I don't have to clog up my list definitions with calculated columns.

Comment: I have since discovered that commas will still show up in certain niche locations (e.g. when I click the chevron in the column header to filter by my custom SPFieldNumber: the filter choices still feature commas)

Comment: Do not use custom column definitions (as in my post above) if you need your list to interact with unknown client software. Unfortunately, we have some copiers here at work that can create a PDF from the 'scanned' document and stuff it into a SharePoint library - unless that library features columns with custom field definitions. POO!